# ConnectionString on my web.config when debuggin a Web Form for SQL server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml

I have been expending a lot of time trying to solve this problem. It seems very simple but I don't find the way. I looked online pretty much everywhere and my problem didn't get an answer. My error is supposed to be in the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ADVENTUREWORKS2012_DATA.MDFConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=FIDEL\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=&quot;C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ADVENTUREWORKS2012_DATA.MDF&quot;;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I am trying to set up an SQL connection by using ASP.NET. I already add the connection by using an sqlDataSource and I can see that the connection is working fine. When I am running the web form I am getting the error above . A book that I am reading say that I might need to change the connection string in the web.config to point correctly to your database but(they don't say how) and as far as I understand my connection string is pointing to the correct place.

here is my selctionList.aspx:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsCustomer" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ADVENTUREWORKS2012_DATA.MDFConnectionString %>" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting" SelectCommand="SELECT [CustomerID], [PersonID], [StoreID], [AccountNumber], [TerritoryID] FROM  [Sales].[Customer]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    </div>
        <asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsCustomer" DataTextField="CustomerID" DataValueField="AccountNumber" OnClick="BulletedList1_Click">
        </asp:BulletedList>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is really frustrated and I don't know what to do, I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Sorry guys here is the error:    An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include those specific errors. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: Thank you very much, I figure out what was the problem and it was not connected with error that I was asking for, I am very sorry ,it was the first time I post something over here.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the name :

```
name="C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ADVENTUREWORKS2012_DATA.MDFConnectionString"
```

to simple one like :

`name="MDFConnectionString"`.

I believe ASP.Net is not liking : and \ as part of the connection string name.

This change needs to be made both in web.config and the aspx page .

Comment: Thank you very much,  the problem with my code was that I didn't define the event onclik and onselecction . Thank you for your time and anwser

Answer (score 0):

Please change your connection string like this. You can write anything in name you don't need to write path of MDF file. Secondly change your data source to just database name. If you are using file than you need to write to full path if you are just pointing to a databse than you only need to write name of database

```
<add name="nameOfConnectionString"
  connectionString="Data Source=FIDEL\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=ADVENTUREWORKS2012_DATA;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```